# Graph as a detail for each row in Jasper Reports report

Tags: graph, jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to make a report which will print a table of results and for each row there will be the data and the graph displayed. How to display the graph for each row? The graph should use different data than are displayed in the row.

Should I use another `Detail` section or `Subreport`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sub-report can make sense if you want to use a separate query to retrieve your data.

If you can get all the data for both the results displayed in a table row plus the data for the graph, then simply add a chart element into the detail section.

(Note that there is only one detail section, so you can't add 'another Detail section')